# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

i m looping through table to find out cell have csstdgreen. i give an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < mytable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < mytable.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                {
                    if(mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"].Equals("csstdgreen"))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
<table id="mytable" runat="server">
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
            <td>
                09:00AM
            </td>
            <td class="csstdgreen">
                00
            </td>
            <td class="csstdgreen" rowspan="3">
                John
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: On which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: Why not debug it and see what is null ? is more fast and easy to debug it than ask it.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this part:

```
<td>
    09:00AM
</td>
```

there is no `class` attribute. So you need to check if it is `null` first:

```
if (mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"] != null &&
    mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"].Equals("csstdgreen")) { 

    // other code...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < mytable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

    string cssClass ;
    for(int j = 0; j < mytable.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
    {

    cssClass = mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"];

       if(cssClass != null)
        {
          if(cssClass != String.Empty)
          {}
        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think `mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"]` is `null` in your case.

You need check this for `null`

```
if (mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"] != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Rows[i] != null)
    if(Cells[j] != null)
       if(Cells[j].Attributes["class"] != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

either check for null as

```
if (mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"] != null)
```

or add a class attribute in your

```
<td>      09:00AM  </td>
```

part as

```
<td class="abc">      09:00AM  </td>
```